# How can i choose a different python version after set a virtual enviroment ? im on win10

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, version, project

i have 2 version of python installed on my win10 machine 3.6 and 38

depending on my project

1. how to launch one rather than the other ?
2. Do i need to choose before i set the vrtual enviroment ?

basically i was wondering after setting my virtual enviroment, how to choose the one i want to use for the project ?
any indication?
id love to do like i do in choosing django version.. for example pip install django==2.1 , how can i do for choosing python version ?

Comment: You're using venv? Have you done any research?

Comment: look for CodingWithMitch on YT.he has decent tutorials for you.

Answer (score -1):

(This is assuming you have installed virtualenv package)
(Applies to windows only)
Ideally, you can switch between different virtual environments in python using the following command.

```
.\env\Scripts\activate
```

You can check if it points to right python instance using

```
where python
```

Once you are inside a venv, pip automatically installs packages under that particular version of python (python instance of the venv). So you shouldn't have any issues there.